# API Controlled Email

Tags: .net, email

If I wanted to build an application that gave people "custom" email addresses (like posterous or flickr email for sending content) for use within my web app, is there an application, webservice or specific server that someone could recommend for me to build my code against?

It seems like setting something up like smartermail,and then having an agent poll several thousand accounts every 10 min or so would be a rather unscalable method..?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into [DeployHQ](http://www.deliverhq.com/) from [AtechMedia](http://atechmedia.com/), it's currently in beta but seems to work quite well and their other apps have been very reliable.

It provides email access both to and from your app via an API, it should work well for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup your mail server to forward all email to a single address, then check that address and look at the `To:` header on the emails.

Comment: I thought of that, but my concern was what about instances where the email address is a bcc.. Is that stored in the header somewhere so I would know how to properly route those messages?

Comment: @extreme: Check the documentation for your mailserver.